# CakePHP Routing json response

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am currently using [RestApi plugin for CakePHP 3](https://github.com/multidots/cakephp-rest-api) and I want to be able to append the extension `.json` to URL, like so:

```
domain.com/api/search/abc.json
```

Following CakePHP's docs about [creating RESTful routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-restful-routes) I was able to use the extension without throwing an error.

I have this on my routes.php (edit to add the whole code)

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;

Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});

Plugin::routes();
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
});
```

In my controller, if I do this:

```
public function search($term=''){
    $this->httpStatusCode = 200;
    $this->apiResponse['term'] = $term;
}
```

The response is:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "result": {
        "term": "abc.json" # Notice the .json
    }
}
```

So, I get `abc.json`, when I want `abc`.

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I supposed to strip the `.json` from `$term`?

Comment: Where are the routes that would actually make use of the configured extensions?

Comment: Do you mean this: `$routes->resources('Searches');` ?

Comment: For example, yes... without seeing the actual routes, nobody will be able to tell what might be wrong, or at least be able to rule out possible problems. The routes snippet that you are showing in your question won't do anything.

Comment: Well, routes has the default routes set by cakePHP, plus that piece of code I have added. I edited the question to have the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reusing existing scopes will merge the connected routes to the same routes collection, calls to `RouteBuilder::extensions()` will generally not affect previously connected routes, and they also do not affect reused/reopened scopes.

Quote from the docs:

> Future routes connected in through this builder will have the connected
>   extensions applied. However, setting extensions does not modify existing routes.

**[API > \Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder::extensions()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#_extensions)**

You should add the `extensions()` call in the existing routing scope, so that it affects the routes that are being connected in there *after* the `extensions()` call.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Routing File Extensions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)**